# Tracing boolean functions using a TUL PYNQ Z2 board

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I am trying to trace the output of a simple XOR gate using a PYNQ Z2 board. But the documentation and related tutorials are not helping.

My boolean function is as follows: `function = ['D2 = D0 ^ D1']`.

I am passing it to the boolean generator but how do I check its waveform? I want to send different combinations of D0 and D1 and see D2's waveform for all these combinations, thus verifying the truth table of the gate.

I am a beginner with Xilinx boards, thank you.

My code so far:

```
function_specs = {'XOR_gate': 'D2 = D0 & D1'}
boolean_generator.setup(function_specs)
boolean_generator.run()

xor_gate = {'signal': [
        ['stimulus',
            {'name': 'A', 'pin': 'D0', 'wave': 'hlhl'},
            {'name': 'B', 'pin': 'D1', 'wave': 'l.h.'}],
        ['analysis',
            {'name': 'Output', 'pin': 'D2'}]],
       'foot': {'tock': 1},
       'head': {'text': 'xor_gate'}}

waveform = Waveform(xor_gate)
waveform.display()
```

References I have seen so far:

1. The official PYNQ Documentation (https://pynq.readthedocs.io/en/v2.3/pynq_libraries/logictools.html)
2. The sample codes present in the board.
3. https://github.com/Xilinx/PYNQ_Workshop
4. I even asked a question on the Xilinx forum but to no avail.